# Re-Upload Photos From Camera Roll etc. With "Best Quality"-Setting to OneDrive

Tags: onedrive, photos, uploading

I used the following photo upload setting since i have my phone (Lumia 925):

> Photos => settings => auto upload to OneDrive with: "good
>   quality - may use data plan)"

But Id like to change it, and have all my photos in best quality on my OneDrive, so i reseted the option to:

> Best quality (needs Wi-Fi)

Now it uploads all my new phots in best quality, but i like my old ones to be re-uploaded and overwrtiting the photos which have been uploaded just in good quality.

- Is there a way to achieve this automated with nothing else to do, than set some option on the phone?
- A work-around like manually getting the photos to my PC (e.g., over USB) and then uploading the photos manually back into OneDrive camera roll would by ok, but i dislike the idea.

Hope my intentions are clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to automatically re-upload all images in best quality. You could either manually upload the old photos through the OneDrive app on your phone or go the USB->PC->OneDrive way. Been there...

Comment: So i reupload them in the onedrive camera roll folder? And this does not lead to some synchronisation problems with the camera roll of my phone?

Comment: No there should be no problems as your phone does not synchronize the photos - it just uploads new ones once. If you delete pics from your phone they'll still be on OneDrive.

Comment: ok thanks, but slightly OT: this means i can't bring my camera roll from my old phone to my new?

Comment: you would have to manually copy the photos onto your phone as well. but if they are on OneDrive you can access them through the app.